# python integer approximation

Tags: math, python-3.2

In python the function `math.log(1000, 10)` returns
2.9999999998 or some approximate value (neraly every third integer does that)

Which firstly is kind of messed up even though I imagine there's not much (except divisibility tests) to do about it.
And secondly it's not the value I want of course, how should I proceed? Casting to int will clearly return 2 and not 3... So what method is used to get the round to nearest int? In this case and in general, please.

Comment: `3>> math.log10(1000)`
`3.0`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: @Zhenya thanks for the article but even though I'm not a computer scientist, I imagined much of this. So it wasn't an answer nor really interesting unless you like long ass technical papers.

Answer (score 1):

Someone removed his/her answer before I could accept it, so I write mine which is no more than a summary.

Two options that I liked:

In this particular case, since the operation was `math.log(1000, 10)`, it could be replaced with `math.log10(1000)` which shows much greater precision.

In a more general case, round(math.log(1000, 10)) will round 2.999... to the integer 3 so this would be more what was asked.

Comment: The problem with that, and probably the reason the answer was removed, is that it also rounds `math.log10(500)` for example to 3. `math.log10` does quite well, but `math.log10(10**110)` returns `110.00000000000001`, as does `math.log10(10**110 - 10**93)`. And `math.log10(10**20 - 10**5)` returns `20.0`. If you want exact results, you cannot avoid doing integer arithmetic.